# jQuery UI resizable width as a function of height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

With the jQuery `resizable()` method how do you make it so that

```
width = 31 + $('idName').height()
```

I'm re-sizing a video player, the controls are constantly 31 pixels, which is good because many embedded videos whose controls get re-sized are unusable.

I'd like it to go from, let's say:

```
620/378 (620/347+31)
```

to

```
310/189 (310/158+31)
```

**Sorry I forgot to mention**, the div is the id being accessed with the jQuery `resizable()` method, the way the video player (it's just an HTML5 `object` element) is being re-sized is that I set its height and width to 100% in my CSS file, this allows it to constantly re-size itself compared to the div object.

Comment: What is $('idName')? The frame with the player inside? Please be more specific in what you need, your question isn't clear at all

Answer (score 0):

jQuery **UI** resizable() makes an element resizable, you still need to act on the resize() event

based on your first equation

```
$('#idname').resize(function() {
    $(this).width( 31 + $(this).height() );
});
```

But i don't think this will give you what you want.

It may be better to look into the aspectRatio parameter of resizable() and maybe need not worry about the event at all

```
$( "#idname" ).resizable({
      aspectRatio: 620 / 378
});
```

Comment: Yeah what I've been doing for the moment is using the `aspectRatio` parameter and not worrying too hard.